# Cannot run .py script on screen

Tags: python, linux, gnu-screen

I am trying to run .py script on Linux screen. Once I create the screen I change directory to the location of the script and next try to run it:
`python script_name.py`, but I don't receive a response. Could you please advise how to resolve it? Thank you in advance.

I tried to:

1. `screen -S screen_name`
2. `cd location_of_the_script`
3. `python script_name.py`

I would like to have my script running on the screen and then detach from this screen.

Comment: Could you share if there's any error message and your script?

Comment: There is no error message - only empty commandline. The script was previously launched hundreds of times by different users. I am trying to run it from root.

Answer (score 0):

`screen -S <name>` (make screen name)

`screen -r <name>` (attach if you are not attached, but you should be)

`cd /location/of/script` (get to your script)

`python your_script.py` (run your script)

`^a d` that is, Ctl + a, then d (detach from screen)

Here is a link to a Linux screen cheat sheet:
http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

I would also recommend using tmux instead of Linux screen.

Comment: I tried the same commands, however there is no log informing that the script is running (it should be).

Answer (score 0):

It is even better to run `byobu` instead of `screen` and `tmux`, since it provides additional system information and you can still choose to select `screen` as a backend.

```
$ byobu
$ cd /location/of/python/script
$ python script.py
```

Then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach.

**Note:** If you get a response or not, will depend fully on your script. 
To determine if it is running you could try something like `ps -u root | grep script.py` or `time python script.py` which prints the runtime to std.out.

Comment: Normally, there are logs in the script. I will try your solution - thanks a lot.